# Parse email address in Oracle to count number of addresses with 3 or less chars before @ sign

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I need to count number of email addresses in a db that have 3 or less characters before the @ sign, for example ab@test.com.

The parsename function isn't present in Oracle and I'm not sure how to write a regexp for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex is overkill for this. All you need is

`instr(t.email, '@') < 5 AND instr(t.email, '@') > 0`

Edited with correction from the comments.

Comment: This is probably much faster than a regexp.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up figuring out on my own, the end result looked like this: SELECT count(*)
from something
where instr(email, '@', 1) <= 3;

Comment: I still maintain you're off by one. For a 3 character address before the @ sign, the result of your expression is 4.

Comment: DCookie is right. The `instr` returns 4 for joe@example.com, so the test should be < 5.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you want is:

```
^[^@]{0,3}@
```

In English, that's:

- Start of string
- between 0 and three things that aren't an at sign.
- an at sign.

Comment: Thank you the English translation +1

Answer (score 2):

You could define the WHERE clause & use COUNT, or skip to use REGEXP_COUNT instead:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(t.email, '^[^@]{0,3}@', 1, 'i') RESULT
  FROM TABLE t;
```

Using COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.email, '^[^@]{0,3}@')
```

Reference:

- [Oracle Regular Expression Syntax](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Be aware that REGEXP is Oracle 10g+ -- there's no regular expression support in Oracle versions earlier than that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little problem with following
instr(t.email, '@') < 5

this query will work provided t.email has a '@' !  other wise it will return those entries also where t.email is not having '@'

Comment: you are right, fortunately that's not an issue here because the email format is validated on entry. Just needed to see if we can implement stronger validation.